# getting cookie ID using stringify in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I am using the following code to get the cookieID of a specific website:

```
    var request = require('request');
    var Cookie = require('request-cookies').Cookie;

    request.get('http://dmp.theadex.com/d/753/i/2.gif', function(err, response, body) {
      var rawcookies = response.request.headers['set-cookie'];
      //console.log(response.headers);
      for (var i in rawcookies) {
        var cookie = new Cookie(rawcookies[i]);
        //console.log(cookie.key, cookie.value);
      }
    }).on('redirect', function () {
      let a = this.response.headers['set-cookie'];
      //console.log(_.isArray(a));
      console.log('a = ', a);
      let cookieText = a[0];
      //console.log('cookieText', cookieText);
      let split = cookieText.split("'");
      console.log('split = ', split[0].split(";")[0]);

    });
```

The output is the following:
a=  [ 'axd=1001413541554540210; expires=Thu, 24-May-2018 13:54:54 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=.theadex.com' ]
split=  axd=1001413541554540210

So the code is working as it should, but extracting the cookieID from the array (a) is not that efficient I guess. Does anyone have a better solution to get around this(maybe a module or a handy feature)? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `set-cookie-parser` npm module.

Using the URL from your example and intercepting the redirect:

```
const request = require('request');
const setCookieParser = require('set-cookie-parser'); 

request.get({
  url: 'http://dmp.theadex.com/d/753/i/2.gif',
  followRedirect: false
}, (err, res, body) => {
  if ((res.statusCode >= 300) && (res.statusCode < 400)) {
    const cookies = setCookieParser.parse(res);
    console.log(cookies);
  }
})
```

Returns:

```
[ { name: 'axd',
    value: '1001413550129520030',
    expires: 2018-05-24T23:29:52.000Z,
    maxAge: 31536000,
    path: '/',
    domain: '.theadex.com' } ]
```

Comment: Any idea how to request the same link multiple times(i.e 1000)?